# Export more than one variable in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js

I'm trying to export more than one variable in ES6:

exports.js

```
var TestObject = Parse.Object.extend('TestObject')
var Post = Parse.Object.extend('Post')

export default TestObject
export Post
```

main.js:

```
import TestObject from '../store'
import Post from '../store'

var testObject = new TestObject() // use Post in the same way
testObject.save(json).then(object => {
  console.log('yay! it worked', object)
})
```

I understand that there's only one default value so I only used `default` in the first item.

However, I get this error message:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /home/alex/node/my-project/src/store/index.js: Unexpected token (9:7)
   7 | 
   8 | export default TestObject
>  9 | export Post
```

Maybe I'm doing it the wrong way?

Comment: Just a wild guess but have you tried adding a semicolon at the end of the first `export` line?

Comment: @Pointy I tried that. Same error.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

That is not valid syntax. You can do

```
export { Post }
```

or even just

```
export var Post = Parse.Object.extend('Post')
```

or shorten the whole file to

```
export default Parse.Object.extend('TestObject')
export var Post = Parse.Object.extend('Post')
```

Your imports are also incorrect, you'll want to do

```
import TestObject, { Post } from '../store'
```

This is if you really want a single default export and a separate named export. You can also just make two named exports and have no default if you want, e.g.

```
export var TestObject = Parse.Object.extend('TestObject');
export var Post = Parse.Object.extend('Post');
```

or

```
var TestObject = Parse.Object.extend('TestObject');
var Post = Parse.Object.extend('Post');
export { TestObject, Post };
```

and import with

```
import { TestObject, Post } from '../store'
```

Comment: I'm curious, what difference `export default` and `export var` makes?

Comment: The default export is the one you get when you `import foo from './module'`, if you use `export var SomeThing` you need to import it by name, e.g. `import {SomeThing} from './module';`

Comment: The default becomes the item you import without de-structuring the imported object.

Comment: @MarioTacke It's not destructuring, calling it that just confuses things. It's just an list of names inside `{}`, it's not an object.

Comment: So the only difference is that the object that used `export default` doesn't have curly brackets and the object that used 'export var` needs curly brackets? Both are named something when being imported: `foo`, `SomeThing`.

Comment: @loganfsmyth, you are right, I was confusing things. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @alexchenco Yup, the main difference is that `foo` can be named anything and will always get the default, but `TestObject` needs to match the name of the export. If you wanted to give it a different name in the module where you import it, you'd have to do `import {TestObject as SomeOtherName} from`. `import foo from` is short for `import {default as foo} from`

Comment: @loganfsmyth Oh, so that's the difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 44):

You can export multiple objects like this in ES6

```
var TestObject = Parse.Object.extend('TestObject')
var Post = Parse.Object.extend('Post')

export {
    TestObject,
    Post
}
```

Then, when importing you do it like this:

```
import { TestObject, Post } from './your-file';
```

You can read all about [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) here.

Comment: The edit that was just made invalidated my answer. It is valid to export without giving it a key name in ES6.

Comment: Oh, I see. So the `default` keyword is not required anymore?

Comment: @MarioTacke Yeah I got nothing, no idea why that edit was accepted.

Comment: Correct @alexchenco, you de-structure the imported file instead.

Answer (score 3):

In order to export multiple variables we have to take everything we want to export from a file  inside { } like this -

```
export { <var 1>, <var 2> , <var 3>, ... , <var n>};
```

for default export we can separately write this-

```
export default <var name>;  // there can be only one default export;
```

In you code you can make the following changes -

**exports.js**

```
export { Post };
```

**main.js**

```
import { Post } from '<exports file>';
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJ7i0.png)

Answer (score 1):

export default 
export {}

the name by which you are exporting must be same while importing.

You can also use * while importing .

Answer (score -1):

If it fits your use case you can make the non-default export a property of your default export. I find it makes for cleaner code.

```
const TestObject = Parse.Object.extend('TestObject');
TestObject.Post = Parse.Object.extend('Post');

export default TestObject;
```

Then, when importing you only need to import the default:

```
import TestObject from './your-file.js';
```

Then, you use it like so:

```
TestObject.Post({some, args});
```