# is it possible to destrucure my import statements

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

i want to write below import in one single line. is it possible?

```
 `import SellerAdaptor from '../adaptors/sellers';
  import UserAdaptor from '../adaptors/user';
  import ShopEarnAdaptor from '../adaptors/shop_earn';
  import ProductAdaptor from '../adaptors/product';
  import JobAdaptor from '../adaptors/job';
  import OrderAdaptor from '../adaptors/order';
  import NotificationAdaptor from '../adaptors/notification';
  import CategoryAdaptor from '../adaptors/category';
  import AdminAdaptor from '../adaptors/adminAdaptor';`
```

Comment: Why'd you do that? What's wrong with multiline imports?

Comment: Remove the line breaks, and it would be one single line....

Comment: Do the back ticks (`) belong to your code?

Comment: no you can't but if you need to you can create a factory like module for all imports check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34648195/is-it-possible-to-do-multiple-class-imports-with-es6-babel

Comment: since all of those modules live under `adaptors`, you might as well create an `index.js` file and put all the exports in there. Given that, all the consumers will `import { ... } from '../adaptors'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

Destructuring would let you import many values from one module.

You can't import multiple modules at once.

---

A typical pattern here would be to have an `../adaptors/index` which imported all the modules and then exported them:

```
import SellerAdaptor from './sellers';
import UserAdaptor from './user';
// etc
export { SellerAdaptor, UserAdaptor, etc };
```

Then you would be able to:

```
import { SellerAdaptor, UserAdaptor, etc } from "../adaptors/index";
```

Comment: A better way to write this is `export { default as SellerAdaptor } from './sellers'`.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to write `import { A, B, C } from 'myPackage'`, it's upon `myPackage` and how it has been written.

If they are different files, you can't do it.
If you have one file `adaptors` that `export` the different modules, you can write your imports with the destructuring.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like as follows:

```
import SellerAdaptor from '../adaptors/sellers';
import UserAdaptor from '../adaptors/user';
import ShopEarnAdaptor from '../adaptors/shop_earn';
import ProductAdaptor from '../adaptors/product';
import JobAdaptor from '../adaptors/job';
import OrderAdaptor from '../adaptors/order';
import NotificationAdaptor from '../adaptors/notification';
import CategoryAdaptor from '../adaptors/category';
import AdminAdaptor from '../adaptors/adminAdaptor';


export {
    SellerAdaptor,
    UserAdaptor,
    ShopEarnAdaptor,
    ProductAdaptor,
    JobAdaptor,
    OrderAdaptor,
    NotificationAdaptor,
    CategoryAdaptor,
    AdminAdaptor
}
```

And Then You can Import like as follows

```
import { SellerAdaptor, UserAdaptor} from './<filename>'
```