# Export multiple variables from typescript class

Tags: typescript

I have a the following sample.ts:

```
class Sample {
    var1;
    var2;
    ...
}
export default new Sample();
```

In another class, i imported it using:

```
import sample from './sample';
```

And use it as:

```
sample.var1;
```

But I would like to access var2 without using `sample.var2`.  I thought of exporting `var2` as well, but I'm not sure if that is possible.  I want something like below, so I can use `var2` directly when i import the file.

```
class Sample {...}
export default new Sample(), var2;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export more than one variable in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34645731/export-more-than-one-variable-in-es6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your export statement with

```
const sampleToExport = new Sample();

export sample = sampleToExport;
export var2 = sampleToExport.var2;
```

You can then import it like this:

```
import { sample, var2 } from './sample'
```

Comment: actually i can't export the variable directly, what i did is `const sample = new Sample();  export const samp = sample, variable2 = sample.var2;`  Then `import {samp, variable2} from './sample';`