# Is there any way to export multiple slices from a single slice file? in redux-toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am pretty much new to redux and i am using redux-toolkit here.

Is there any way to export multiple slices from a single slice file in redux-toolkit??

example

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const isAuthenticated = createSlice({
    name: isAuthenticated,
    initialState: false,
    reducers: {
        loginSuccess(state, action) {
            return true;
        },
        logout(state, action) {
            return false;
        },
    },
});

const currentUser = createSlice({
    name: currentUser,
    initialState: {},
    reducers: {
        setUserDetailsApi(state, action) {
            return action.user;
        },
    },
});

export const { loginSuccess, logout } = isAuthenticated.actions;
export const { setUserDetailsApi } = currentUser.actions;

export default isAuthenticated.reducer;

//how should i export currentUser.reducer??
```

Actually i am trying to replicate my code of vanilla redux here which has multiple reducer in a single file.

Please correct me if i am doing anything wrong here. Thanks

Comment: don't use export default if you are going to use export const. change everything to export const and import using `{ }` destructuring

Comment: @SinanYaman i tried this export const{ isAuthenticated.reducer, currentUser.reducer  }; but its a syntax error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To return multiple reducers in the same file you could use `combineReducers`

```js
import { combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export default combineReducers({
    isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated.reducer,
    currentUser: currentUser.reducer
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export {
  someName: isAuthenticated.reducer, 
  someOtherName: currentUser.reducer
}
```

and inside other component

```
import { someName, someOtherName } from '...'
```

Comment: `SyntaxError:Unexpected token, expected "," (128:12)`



`export {
> 128 |     someName: isAuthenticated.reducer, 
      |             ^
  129 |     someOtherName: currentUser.reducer
  130 | }`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34645731/export-more-than-one-variable-in-es6